# add nested feature for Accordion component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, recursion, next.js

I have a project with Next.js and typescript and in this project, I have an accordion component like this

```tsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import classes from './Accordion.module.scss';
import { IAccordion, IAccordionItem } from './IAccordion';

const AccordionItem: React.FC<IAccordionItem> = ({
    accordionItem,
    isMultiple,
    isActive = false,
    toggleOnlyOneAccordionItemHandler,
    itemClassName,
}) => {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(isActive);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsVisible(isActive);
    }, [isActive]);
    const toggleAccordionItemHandler = () => {
        setIsVisible(prevState => !prevState);
    };
    return (
        <div className={`${classes.item} ${itemClassName}`}>
            <div
                className={classes.title}
                onClick={() =>
                    isMultiple
                        ? toggleAccordionItemHandler()
                        : toggleOnlyOneAccordionItemHandler(accordionItem.id)
                }
            >
                <h2>{accordionItem.title}</h2>
                <span>{isVisible ? '-' : '+'}</span>
            </div>
            <div
                className={`${classes.content} ${
                    isVisible ? classes.show : ''
                }`}
            >
                {accordionItem.content}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export const Accordion: React.FC<IAccordion> = ({
    accordionItems,
    isMultiple,
    className,
    itemClassName,
}) => {
    const [selectedAccordionItemId, setSelectedAccordionItemId] = useState<
        null | number | string
    >(null);
    const toggleOnlyOneAccordionItemHandler = (
        accordionItemId: number | string
    ) => {
        if (selectedAccordionItemId === accordionItemId) {
            setSelectedAccordionItemId(null);
            return;
        }
        setSelectedAccordionItemId(accordionItemId);
    };

    return (
        <div className={`${classes.accordion} ${className}`}>
            {accordionItems.map(accordionItem => {
                return (
                    <React.Fragment key={accordionItem.id}>
                        <AccordionItem
                            accordionItem={accordionItem}
                            isMultiple={isMultiple}
                            itemClassName={itemClassName}
                            isActive={
                                selectedAccordionItemId === accordionItem.id
                            }
                            toggleOnlyOneAccordionItemHandler={
                                toggleOnlyOneAccordionItemHandler
                            }
                        />
                    </React.Fragment>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};

Accordion.defaultProps = {
    isMultiple: true
}
```

it is the interface file

```ts
import React from 'react';

export interface IAccordion {
    accordionItems: {
        id: string | number;
        title: string | React.ReactElement;
        content: string | React.ReactElement;
    }[];
    isMultiple?: boolean;
    className?: string;
    itemClassName?: string;
}

export interface IAccordionItem
    extends Pick<IAccordion, 'isMultiple' | 'itemClassName'> {
    accordionItem: IAccordion['accordionItems'][0];
    isActive: boolean;
    toggleOnlyOneAccordionItemHandler: (
        id: IAccordion['accordionItems'][0]['id']
    ) => void;
}
```

and it is the CSS file

```css
.accordion{
  width: 500px;
}

.item{
  background: #f0ebe1;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.title{
  color: #85662b;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.content{
  color: #8b7f75;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1);
}

.content.show{
  height: auto;
  max-height: 9999px;
  transition: max-height 0.5s cubic-bezier(1,0,1,0);
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

and I use the Accordion component in index.tsx like this

```tsx
<Accordion
    accordionItems={[
        {
            title: 'Question1',
            id: 'Question1',
            content:
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque dignissimos dolore earum e' +
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque dignissimos dolore earum e Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque dignissimos dolore earum e' +
                ' Cumque dignissimos dolore earum explicabo incidunt omnis pariatur repellat sapiente soluta voluptate?',
        },
        {
            title: 'Question2',
            id: 'Question2',
            content:
                'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusantium ad animi aspernatur aut beatae culpa eius esse expedita fugit hic ipsa laboriosam laborum maxime optio, quis sint tempora ullam vitae voluptatum. Eum, facere, possimus!',
        },
    ]}
/>
```

now I want to add nested feature in my Accordion component and I want to add children property into the accordionItems prop like below

```tsx
accordionItems={[
    {
        title: 'Question1',
        id: 'Question1',
        content:
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque dignissimos dolore earum e' +
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque dignissimos dolore earum e Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque dignissimos dolore earum e' +
            ' Cumque dignissimos dolore earum explicabo incidunt omnis pariatur repellat sapiente soluta voluptate?',
        children: {
            title: 'Question1.1',
            id: 'Question1.1',
            content: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque dignissimos dolore earum e',
            children: {
                title: 'Question1.1.1',
                id: 'Question1.1.1',
                content: 'Lorem simos dolore earum e',
            }
        }
    },
    {
        title: 'Question2',
        id: 'Question2',
        content:
            'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusantium ad animi aspernatur aut beatae culpa eius esse expedita fugit hic ipsa laboriosam laborum maxime optio, quis sint tempora ullam vitae voluptatum. Eum, facere, possimus!',
    },
]}
```

now I have two challenges:

1. How can I create this kind of nested Accordions? I think I should somehow create a recursive function for handling that.
2. I don't know how can I add type for children property into my accordionItems property in IAccordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now is the time for you to learn **mutual recursion**.

Here's a minimal, verifiable example of a recursive type and corresponding React component. Notice -

- `List` builds zero or more `ListItem` components
- `ListItem` optionally builds a `List`

```js
function List({ items = [] }) {
  return <ul>
    {items.map(item => <ListItem key={item.title} {...item} />)}
  </ul>
}

function ListItem({ title, sublist = [] }) {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false)
  const onClick = e => { e.stopPropagation(); setOpen(!open) }
  return <li onClick={onClick}>
    {open || sublist.length == 0 ? "➖" : "➕"}
    {title}
    {open && <List items={sublist} />}
  </li>
}

const menu = [
  { title: "Clothing", sublist: [ { title: "Athletics" }, { title: "Formal" }, { title: "Casual" } ] },
  { title: "Electronics", sublist: [ { title: "Computers" }, { title: "Mobile Phones", sublist: [ { title: "Apple" }, { title: "Android" } ] } ] }
]
        
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app")).render(
  <List items={menu} />
)
```

```css
li { list-style-type: none; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Using `event.stopPropagation()` ensures only the clicked item will toggle, and not the item's ancestors.

As expected, the types are mutually recursive too -

```
type tlist = Array<tlistitem>

type tlistitem = {
  title: string,
  sublist?: tlist
}
```

```
function List(props: { items: tlist }) // ...
function ListItem(props: tlistitem) // ...
```

If you enjoyed this, you can read my [other answers about mutual recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+mutual+recursion) to learn more ways to apply the technique.